# "Unhandled promise rejection " only with FireFox on local

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

here is the async function ($mydb is the Dexie instance):

```
const result= await this.$mydb.MYTABLE.where('from').equals(taskRef).or('to').equals(taskRef).toArray()
```

inside a VueJS component method

-> serve localhost on Chrome : No error

-> serve localhost on FF : No error

vuecli build

Browse local dist file on Chrome : No error

Browse local dist file on FF ...=

```
Unhandled promise rejection
=> name: "TransactionInactiveError", message: "A request was placed against a transaction which is currently not active, or which is finished."
```

just ... why ???? Why only on FireFox(67) in local browsing ?????

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is only for firefox67 with dev console opened

https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/831